# Is there a way to create simple animations "on the fly" in modern OpenGL?

Tags: animation, opengl, dynamic, lwjgl

I think this requires a bit of background information:
I have been modding Minecraft for a while now, but I alway wanted to make my own game, so I started digging into the freshly released LWJGL3 to actually get things done. Yes, I know it's a bit ow level and I should use an engine and stuff...indeed, I already tried some engines and they never quite match what I want to do, so I decided I want to tackle the problem at its root.
So far, I kind of understand how to render meshes, move the "camera", etc. and I'm willing to take the learning curve.

But the thing is, at some point all the tutorials start to explain how to load models and create skeletal animations and so on...but I think I do not really want to go that way. A lot of things in working with Minecraft code was awful, but I liked how I could create models and animations from Java code. Sure, it did not look super realistic, but since I'm not great with Blender either, I doubt having "classic" models and animations would help. Anyway, in that code, I could rotate a box around to make a creature look at a player, I could use a sinus function to move legs and arms (or wings, in my case) and that was working, since Minecraft used immediate mode and Java could directly tell the graphics card where to draw each vertex.

**So, actual question(s): Is there any good way to make dynamic animations in modern (3.3+) OpenGL? My models would basically be a hierarchy of shapes (boxes or whatever) and I want to be able to rotate them on the fly. But I'm not sure how to organize that. Would I store all the translation/rotation-matrices for each sub-shape? Would that put a hard limit on the amount of sub-shapes a model could have? Did anyone try something like that?**

Edit: For clarification, what I did looked something like this:

Create a model: https://github.com/TheOnlySilverClaw/Birdmod/blob/master/src/main/java/silverclaw/birds/client/model/ModelOstrich.java
The model is created as a bunch of boxes in the constructor, the render and setRotationAngles methods set scale and rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow one opengl tutorial in order to understand the basics.

Let me suggest ["Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming"](http://web.archive.org/web/20140209181347/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/), and especially [this chapter](http://web.archive.org/web/20140208140137/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Fun%20with%20Matrices.html), where you move one robot arm with multiple joints.

[image]

I did a port in java using jogl [here](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples), but you can easily port it over lwjgl.

Comment: I'm already following [this LWJGL3-book](https://www.gitbook.com/book/lwjglgamedev/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/details) and a bunch of OpenGL tutorials, but that seems to include what I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is exactly skeletal animation, the only difference being the fact you do not want to load animations for your bones but want to compute / generate transforms on the fly.

You basically have a hierarchy of bones, and geometry attached to it. It looks like you want to manipulate this geometry "rigidly", so before sending your meshes / transforms to the GPU (the classic way), you want to start by computing the new transforms in model or world space, then send those freshly computed matrices to draw your geometries on the gpu the standard way.

As Sorin said, to compute each transform you simply have to iterate over your hierarchy and accumulate transforms given the transform of the parent bone and your local transform w.r.t the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You can have your hierarchy of shapes and store a relative transform for each.
For example the "player" whould have a translation to 100,100, 10 (where the player is), and then the "head" subcomponent would have an additional translation of 0,0,5 (just a bit higher on the z axis).

You can store these as matrices (they can encode translation, roation and scaling) and use glPushMatrix and glPop matrix to add and remove a matrix to a stack maintained by openGL.

The `draw()` function(or whatever you call it) should look something like :

```
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrix(my_transform);  // You can also just have glTranslate, glRotate or anything else.
// Draw my mesh
for (child : children) { child.draw(); }
glPopMatrix();
```

This gives you a hierarchical setup so that objects move with their parent. Alternatively you can have a stack in the main memory and do the multiplications yourself (use a library). I think the openGL stack may have a limit (implementation dependent), but if you handle it yourself the only limit is the amount of ram you can use. Once all the matrices are multiplied rendering is done in the same amount of time, that is it doesn't matter for performance how deep a mesh is in the hierarchy.

For actual animations you need to compute the intermediate transformations. For example for a crouch animation you probably want to have a few frames in between so that the camera doesn't just jump to the low position. You can do this with a time based linear interpolation between the start and end positions, but this only covers simple animations and you still have to implement it yourself.

Anything more complicated (i.e. modify the mesh based on the bone links) you would need to implement yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I think your answer covers the "old" push/popMatrix-operations that Minecraft/LWJGL2.x was doing anyway, but which are not available in shader-based OpenGL?

Comment: Yes, those calls are deprecated, but the concept behind remains